# Returning model object from Controller to Ajax jquery not working in Spring mvc

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to return a model object from spring mvc controller back to jquery ajax method but it is returning blank as the response

jsp:

```
$( "#dialog-link10" ).click(function( event ) {
var appname= $("#dialog-link10").text();
alert(appname);
if(appname == 'RS Applications') {
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : 'abc.html',
    dataType: 'JSON' ,
    data: 
        {"id" : $("#dialog-link10").text()}
    ,
    success : function(data) {
        alert('success')
        alert('data')

    }
});}
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/abc")
@ResponseBody
public  Model helloWorld2( @RequestParam("id") String id, Model model) {

    System.out.println("*****"+id);

    List <String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
    List <String> list2=new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("here");

        list1.add("abc");
        list1.add("abc2");
        list1.add("abc3");
        list1.add("abc4");

        model.addAttribute("list1", list1);

        return model;
        }
```

This is not generating success alert as well.
Please suggest

Comment: Are you seeing this `*****<id>`  in the console when you make the ajax request? I think your requests are not reaching the controller.

Comment: yes id is getting printed...its going inside the controller but not returning from there.... if i change the return type as string instead of list it returns success but when i am trying to retrieve list from controller method as response, it's not workin

Comment: Do you see anything in the console? Are there any errors for message conversion, unsupported media etc? Did you register jackson message converters in your Spring config file? Post the Config file here.

Comment: yes i have added jackson mapper in the dispatcher-servlet:

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven ignore-default-model-on-redirect="true">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

Comment: the error i am getting is "Not Acceptable"

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace...from the moment the request is sent from the browser?

Comment: Also, try setting contentType in the ajax request. `$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : 'abc.html',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
   ...........................});`

Answer (score 0):

Your method should return directly the list, as a json, no need to put it in the model and return the model. Also check if you have an error in your callback ajax.

Comment: And in the debug browser, what is the result?

Comment: i checked adding error, it returns error, is there anyway to check the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying `dataType: 'JSON'` in your ajax call, but you are not converting your response object (model) to json in your controller.

From the jQuery [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for `dataType` setting:

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string)

You'll probably want to reference a json serializer (unless you want to write your own) - but the important part is serializing your `model` to json in your response. For example (using [json-io](https://github.com/jdereg/json-io)):

```
String jsonModel = JsonWriter.objectToJson(model);
return jsonModel;
```

You can then access the string array contained in your json response object in the following way:

```
success : function(data) {
     for (i = 0; i < data.list1.length; i++){
          alert(data.list1[i]);
     }
}
```

And a fiddle example for [reading json objects](http://jsfiddle.net/86cwvw9f/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem and it took me several hours to find out the problem.
Just remove "Model model" from your parameter.
Use a `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, Object>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to the RequestMapping annotation

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/abc", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Also, you may not need the Model paramater in the method.